# How can I reference one dylib from another?

Tags: macos, qt, bundle, dylib

I have a Qt application that depends on a dylib and have successfully got that building into a .app bundle. The app is located in Contents/MacOS whilst the dylib is located in Contents/Frameworks.

The steps that I go through are to build the dylib and app, run macdeployqt on the .app bundle, copy the dylib into Contents/Frameworks before running install_name_tool on the dylib.

Now I am trying to reference another dylib from the existing one but I am getting "Library not loaded" and "image not found" errors when running the app.

This is after running install_name_tool on the second dylib. Is there anything else that I should be doing?

Comment: Use *otool -L* on the first dylib to see where it expects the 2nd dylib to reside.

Comment: When I run otool -L I get lib<name>.dylib as the path to the 2nd dylib. As I said, both of these are located in Contents/Frameworks.

Comment: Then that's the problem; dyld, locates dependent dynamic libraries using the full path to each dylib.["A run-path-relative pathname uses the @rpath macro to specify a path relative to a directory to be determined at runtime"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I've got it working. Coming from a Windows / Linux background, it is taking some time to get my head around the Mac way.